# Normals not completely baking

Tags: normals, baking

So, I'm trying to bake a high-poly mesh onto a low-poly mesh. I made sure to check the "Selected to active" box. And I've played around with the ray distance. But no matter how I tweak it, the normals come out looking incomplete, or even spotty. Also, I always select the high-poly mesh first. It's been a while since I've done this, so I bet I'm just rusty, and have missed a step. The picture shows the two meshes in the same location, ready to bake. The idea is to get the higher-poly soil detail onto the normal map.

[image][image]

I want to thank you so much for taking the time to post a response to my question! I'm sure we're on the right path to finding a solution. So I have tried baking it a few times, with different sizes of the high-poly mesh, and with adjustments to the ray length. But I still cannot quite get the detail on the soil to show up. And the lines around the pot look a little odd now... Maybe it is because I didn't UV unwrap it very well?

Comment: Also thank you all in advance!

Comment: Try shrinking your lowpoly object untill it is encased by the highpoly object. It's normal rays are only projected outwards.

Comment: OH you said shrink the low poly object! Lemme try that!

Comment: Ok. The detail for the soil is visible now, but the odd lines are still there.